# How do you pull a value from a URL tag and modify it in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm in marketing so I use URL tags to pass specific information to my pre-sale pages.

I'm looking to write the HTML so that it will read the the tag (for example image=1_1) remove the last 2 digits (so we are left with 1 in this example) and then add .jpg to it (1.jpg)so it loads that image from a specific folder.

How would I got about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I should have work my answer according to your approach.